# Does Strongbox have a REST API and where can I find the specification?

Tags: rest, strongbox

I was wondering where I could find the REST API documentation for Strongbox and if at all it has one? Could somebody please tell me where to find this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currently two ways to get the REST API documentation for Strongbox:

- Get the [strongbox-distribution](https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/releases) and start it locally.
- Clone the [Strongbox](https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox) project, (if you're interested in developing new functionality for Strongbox) and build it (by following the build instructions [here](https://strongbox.github.io/developer-guide/building-the-code.html)) and start it locally.

You can then navigate to http://localhost:48080/docs/rest/api.html (as explained [here](https://strongbox.github.io/user-guide/rest-api.html) in our wiki).

**Disclaimer:** I am the project owner of Strongbox.